# 'A' always in Caps, and L-Shift types 'A' for Toshiba A665

Tags: keyboard-layout, toshiba-laptop

I just got a brand new Toshiba Satellite A665

There are two weird problems

- My left-shift key types the letter A
- And my letter A key is always in caps.

I can actually type an A by hitting Caps-lock and then a.

This is so weird... what could be the problem? I could just return the darn thing tomorrow morning but I'm curious to see if there is a simple fix.

Comment: It might be helpful to know what OS.

Comment: the OS is Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the internal contacts between <kbd>A</kbd> & <kbd>shift</kbd> are shorted - thereby

- hitting <kbd>A</kbd> results in <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> signal being sent
- hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> results in <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> signal being sent

Comment: Right on. That is definitely how it's behaving. I'm still wondering if it could be a software issue rather than a physical short-circuit.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know roughly when this started (i.e. after you installed or uninstalled a program, during the attack of a virus, after your keyboard got struck by lightning)?

1. I would try making sure that you are on a regular English layout (I'm not sure if there is some goofy layout that could cause this).
2. I would also check for any special drivers you might have for your keyboard and update/reinstall them. Maybe they got corrupt.

-Good Luck!

Comment: the computer is brand-new. The problem appeared during the OS initialization

Comment: In that case @AlexR, I would have to agree with @Sathya. It must be a physical issue with the keyboard. Sorry I could not help you more.